# Synonym for "under-developed location" used by someone who is well off?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

In a fiction I am writing when one of the characters returns home to his wife he finds here sister's there as well. when asked why they've been there for the past month one explains how they are looking for real estate.

The sister who says this is well off and comes from another world which is far advance so looked down on Earth as underdeveloped. I had a line like this in mind

> Melly: we thought to get some real estate out here on the boonies
>   Chrono: please don't refer to Earth as the boonies

I originally thought of this as it is how [Mimi Houllier von Schwarzlang](http://atelier.wikia.com/wiki/Mimi) refers to Totori's home of [Alanya](http://atelier.wikia.com/wiki/Alanya), however, googleing the definition of boonies in google I got

> short for boondocks.

And a google definition search for that resulted in

> rough or isolated country.

Going onto thesaurus.com for [Synonym of boondocks](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/boondocks) and obviously boonies is in there so looking at it's [Synonyms](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/boonies) but none are really what I'd imagine someone who's well off would say.

Back to the boondocks synonyms and i saw backwards which is what Earth would be in comparison so I looked up it's [Synonyms](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/backwoods) but it's roughly the same as what the boonies had. I did think of maybe Terra Incognita but it's definition is

> unknown or unexplored territory.

However Earth is known, just monitored.

So I am wondering, what word can I use for "under-developed location" which would be said by someone who is well off/rich?

NOTE: the reason why Melly would be looking to move to earth is another sister is sickly and Melly believes that an under-developed world won't have any of the ailments which could aggravate the sister's condition (with lesser ones easily curable within a few minutes)

Comment: Please [edit] this and fix your typos.

Comment: @curiousdannii better? apart from maybe one word and the I's that chrome doesn't pick up i don't see any others

Comment: You left 'rel-estate' in!

Comment: @curiousdannii that didn't come up wrong in Chrome and i always thought it was `relesate` as in one word, not `real estate` as in 2 words (removing the space made it wrong)

Comment: You could use a little humor and similar to a *third world country* you could go up a level and use a "*third solar system planet*  But that's probably stretching it a bit.  @medica's got the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't want to mischaracterize rich people, but a common slang phrase for going somewhere of inferior "quality" is [*slumming it*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Slumming+it):

> to endure conditions or accommodations that are worse than what one is accustomed to; to visit or frequent a place, esp. an amusement spot, considered low in social status. - TFD